# Is there any way to build TensorFlow from source without having internet?

Tags: build, tensorflow, deep-learning, bazel

Currently building tensorflow from source need to connect to internet to download some dependencies. Every time when I rebuild it, bazel will delete what have been downloaded and re-download them.

I wonder if there is any possible way to avoid this by pre-download all the dependencies and just build it without internet?

Comment: do you do `bazel clean` or create new clone directory? If you `git pull` into the same directory, `bazel` should reuse the previously downloaded deps

Comment: So if I do `bazel clean` or create new clone, can I manually download the deps and send to the server machine locally so that I can build from source without the server's access to the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to pre-download 3rd party dependencies, as explained [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5428#issuecomment-258732841).

In tensorflow v0.11.0, they are listed in "tensorflow/workspace.bzl". After downloading files you need, replace links like this:

```
url = "http://www.bzip.org/1.0.6/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz",
```

to

```
url = "file:////mnt/a/usr/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz",
```

Note, that there's about 20 dependencies to download.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a case not well supported by TensorFlow, apparently one way is to build Docker or other VM environment, and distribute that --
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3194#issuecomment-231326381

Answer (score 2):

Bazel automatically caches the external dependencies it downloads.  Is it possible you are:

1. Moving the tensorflow source around
2. Changing the BUILD files it uses for external repositories
3. Building different targets (that might require other dependencies) each time?

If none of those seem likely, can you add the output for running identical bazel builds twice in a row where you're seeing re-downloading behavior, using `--explain`?